# You have no idea what you are talking about. Aren't you? or Don't you?

Tags: parts-of-speech, tag-questions

**You have no idea what you are talking about.**

What is 'what' in the above sentence? Isn't it a relative pronoun?

What question tag should we use in these type of sentences?

Aren't you? or Don't/Do you?

What part should I consider from the sentence to form question tag?

Comment: ***...Do you**?* As opposed to "positive polarity" *You have **some** idea what you are talking about*, for which the tag question would be ***Don't you**?*

Comment: I might use **have you?**

Comment: @KateBunting That's perfectly understandable to us Americans, but we normally wouldn't say it. I guess that it's related to the fact that one can say "Have you any wool?" in BrE but typically not in AmE (i.e., do-support in questions with "to have" as main verb).

Comment: @MarcInManhattan - See [this](https://www.eurocentres.com/blog/you-want-to-use-question-tags-do-you#:~:text=Forming%20tags&text=If%20you%20are%20using%20an,%2C%20haven't%20you%3F%E2%80%9D) - presumably a British English website.

Comment: @KateBunting It doesn't seem to allow your question tag: *If there is no auxiliary verb, then the tag uses the verb “do”.* It indicates a "head office" in Cape Town, so perhaps it's a South African company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: ‘You have no idea what you are talking about, do you?’. ‘Are you’ is for when a person is something, when ‘Do you’ is for when a person is ***doing*** something.

Comment: If a person has no idea about a subject, are they "doing" something? Compare **She hasn't (got) an idea, has she?** and **They have got** *a villa with a swimming pool*, **haven't they?** Both are acceptable in British English.

Comment: @Mari-LouA the thing they are doing is having something or not having something.

Comment: OK, so if the action is having or not having something why  shouldn't the question tag be ***have you***? The phrase "You have an idea" can be made negative without using the auxiliary "do" as in "*You **haven't** an idea*"